# "gzip: stdin: invalid compressed data--format violated" error when extracting a tgz archive

Tags: tar, gzip, ibm-unix-system-services

I have to open a tar file. I used the following command line on my Unix shell:

```
tar xfvz raw-GWA-data.tgz
```

I found the following error message:

```
gzip: stdin: invalid compressed data--format violated
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Then, I tried the following command lines:

```
tar -xvzf raw-GWA-data.tgz   
tar --extract --file raw-GWA-data.tgz  
tar xzf raw-GWA-data.tgz   
tar -xf raw-GWA-data.tgz
```

and I found the same error without the possibility of opening my tar file.

What's wrong? There're alternative ways to open my tar file?

Comment: What does `file raw-GWA-data.tgz` output? It does look like either it's not in gzip format or the file is corrupted.

Comment: If you transferred it from somewhere, how did you transfer it? If using FTP, make sure to use the binary mode.

Comment: the output should be a PED file and a MAP file

Comment: Hi Federica, remember that this site is not about bioinformatics so people here will have no idea what ped or map files are. What Stéphane is telling you is that your tar file is not OK. It was probably not downloaded correctly which is why you get a very informative error telling you it's `invalid compressed data`. That's why Stéphane asked for the output of the command `file raw-GWA-data.tgz` which should help us see if this is actually a compressed tar file. Can you try downloading the file again to see if that works?

Comment: ok sorry! I'll try to download my files again!

Comment: Most likely it's corrupted: some inserted or deleted or changed bytes (like the 0xa transformed to 0xd 0xa or vis versa when transferred in text mode). If it was truncated, you'd get some `gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file`. If it wasn't gzip data at all, you'd get `gzip: stdin: not in gzip format`

Comment: Yep, probably the problam is that as you've just said

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the `hexdump` (here taken with `hexdump -C`) of that file,

```
00000000  1f 8b 08 00 cd b6 e3 4c  00 03 d4 bd 5f 8c 23 5b  |.......L...._.#[|
00000010  7a 1f 46 71 82 80 62 0f  66 0c 3f 04 86 0c 18 0c  |z.Fq..b.f.?.....|
00000020  47 50 68 b2 45 ce f6 ac  e4 36 39 26 05 09 01 12  |GPh.E....69&....|
00000030  19 88 83 20 79 c8 93 b1  92 15 3b 52 bc 57 90 64  |... y.....;R.W.d|
00000040  c4 d1 0d 0a 3b 0c 3b 0f  34 39 e8 16 f4 12 43 0b  |....;.;.49....C.|
00000050  e8 32 45 61 55 7b 8a 5b  67 d2 9d ec e5 d6 e1 ad  |.2EaU{.[g.......|
00000060  33 98 09 ac 0e 79 43 02  f1 9b ae 73 a7 4d 1a bb  |3....yC....s.M..|
00000070  54 15 55 67 d2 8c ef 70  eb 70 ce c9 77 4e 91 dd  |T.Ug...p.p..wN..|
00000080  ec 9e 9e bf 77 f6 1a aa  dd 3b cd 66 93 f5 ab df  |....w....;.f....|
00000090  f7 ef 7c df f9 fb 8f be  f6 9b ff f8 6b bf 79 e7  |..|.........k.y.|
000000a0  b7 76 fe fe 2f fd c7 ff  55 fe 97 fe 93 5f cc ff  |.v../...U...._..|
000000b0  f2 7f fe 5f e6 ff eb ff  e2 3f cd ff 37 1f fc 93  |..._.....?..7...|
000000c0  af ff 83 5f fb ad df ce  7f fd 83 9f fd da ef fc  |..._............|
000000d0  ec af fe c3 9f fd ed af  ff e6 6f e7 7f e5 d7 fe  |..........o.....|
000000e0  41 ec 2d af db 70 fd fc  57 bf 0d 0a 3f ef 7c 65  |A.-..p..W...?.|e|
000000f0  e7 e7 d5 cf db 3b 3b 5f  fd 0d 0a fc fc f9 af dc  |.....;;_........|
```

You'll notice that all the 0x0a bytes (which if interpreted as a character in ASCII would be the newline aka LF / linefeed / `\n` / `^J` character) are preceded by the 0x0d byte (corresponds to carriage return aka CR / `^M` / `\r`).

This kind of corruption can happen when a file is transferred from a Unix machine to a Microsoft machine over FTP without setting the mode to *binary*, then the line endings are converted from LF to CRLF on the fly.

Here, you could reverse that corruption by converting all the CRLFs back to LF with `perl -pe 's/\r\n\z/\n/'` for instance:

```
$ bsdtar tf Downloads/41596_2010_BFnprot2010116_MOESM396_ESM.zip
raw-GWA-data.tgz
$ bsdtar xOf Downloads/41596_2010_BFnprot2010116_MOESM396_ESM.zip | perl -pe 's/\r\n\z/\n/' | bsdtar tvvf -
-rw-r--r--  0 ca3    team152 103669932 Mar  9  2010 hapmap3r2_CEU.CHB.JPT.YRI.founders.no-at-cg-snps.bed
-rw-r--r--  0 ca3    team152  29166116 Mar  9  2010 hapmap3r2_CEU.CHB.JPT.YRI.founders.no-at-cg-snps.bim
-rw-r--r--  0 ca3    team152      8813 Mar  9  2010 hapmap3r2_CEU.CHB.JPT.YRI.founders.no-at-cg-snps.fam
-rw-r--r--  0 ca3    team152  10664954 Mar  8  2010 hapmap3r2_CEU.CHB.JPT.YRI.no-at-cg-snps.txt
-rw-r--r--  0 ca3    team152       417 Jan  7  2010 high-LD-regions.txt
-rw-r--r--  0 ca3    team152       718 Feb 16  2010 imiss-vs-het.Rscript
-rw-r--r--  0 ca3    team152         9 Mar  9  2010 pca-populations.txt
-rw-r--r--  0 ca3    team152       283 Mar  3  2010 plot-IBD.Rscript
-rw-r--r--  0 ca3    team152       776 Jun  4  2010 plot-pca-results.Rscript
-rwxr-xr-x  0 ca3    team152  11747611 Jan  6  2010 raw-GWA-data.map
-rw-r--r--  0 ca3    team152 2540057786 Jan 14  2010 raw-GWA-data.ped
-rw-r--r--  0 ca3    team152       1217 Mar  8  2010 run-IBD-QC.pl
-rw-r--r--  0 ca3    team152        327 Mar 11  2010 run-diffmiss-qc.pl
-rw-r--r--  0 ca3    team152     511429 Jan  7  2010 raw-GWA-data.prune.in
Archive Format: GNU tar format,  Compression: gzip
```